# terminating the integration of ode after some convergence test in DiffEqPhysics Julia

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

Recently I started to be familiar with DiffEqPhysics and DifferentialEquations package of Julia. I'm wondering if there is a way (like callback functions) to terminate the solver with certain output convergence condition. For example if the result obtained in previous step (or a range of previous steps) does not differ from the solution at current step by a threshold value, then end the process after the current step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use callbacks to do this. In the callback, doing `terminate!(integrator)` will halt the integration. In the docs [this example shows using callbacks with `terminate!` in more detail](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions.html#Example-2:-Terminating-an-Integration-1).

But instead of building your own, for terminating at a steady state you can use [`TerminateSteadyState`](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_library.html#TerminateSteadyState-1) from the callback library. The callback library is just a set of pre-built callbacks, and this one terminates when the derivative is sufficiently small.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.